# Add custom created post objects to the Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a plug in that handles events.  This plug in does not handle recurring events, so we'd like to add this functionality.

I have a query already written that is functioning and pulling in the events we want.  It looks like this:

```
SELECT posts.*, metaStartDate.meta_value as EventStartDate, meta.meta_value as EventRepeats, metaTimeSpans.meta_value as EventTimeRanges
FROM $wpdb->posts posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta meta ON (posts.ID = meta.post_id AND meta.meta_key = '_EventRepeats')
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta metaStartDate ON (posts.ID = metaStartDate.post_id AND metaStartDate.meta_key = '_EventStartDate')
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta metaRepeatsUntil ON (posts.ID = metaRepeatsUntil.post_id AND metaRepeatsUntil.meta_key = '_EventRepeatsUntil')
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta metaTimeSpans ON (posts.ID = metaTimeSpans.post_id AND metaTimeSpans.meta_key = '_EventTimeRanges')
WHERE posts.post_type = 'tribe_events'
AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND meta.meta_value != 'once'
AND '$queryDate 00:00:00' BETWEEN metaStartDate.meta_value AND metaRepeatsUntil.meta_value
```

As I mentioned, this is fetching the events we want, but how do I then add them to the Wordpress loop so that things like `have_posts()` and `the_post()` work?

Edit: It looks like the correct answer is to uses WP_Query, but is there a way to do a big query like that in WP_Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: **you *should* use** `WP_Query` **whenever dealing with native WordPress' database tables**, even for your custom posts. Nevertheless, [WordPress provides the `wpdb` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)(you *must* read this link) for database manipulation, which *should* be used to work with your own custom database tables.

So, if you really want to execute that query, you should use [wpdb's SELECT Generic Result](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) and add a little tweak to ["convert" it to a WordPress loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query):

```
<?php
// Your custom query
$querystr = "
    SELECT posts.*, metaStartDate.meta_value as EventStartDate, meta.meta_value as EventRepeats, metaTimeSpans.meta_value as EventTimeRanges
    FROM $wpdb->posts posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta meta ON (posts.ID = meta.post_id AND meta.meta_key = '_EventRepeats')
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta metaStartDate ON (posts.ID = metaStartDate.post_id AND metaStartDate.meta_key = '_EventStartDate')
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta metaRepeatsUntil ON (posts.ID = metaRepeatsUntil.post_id AND metaRepeatsUntil.meta_key = '_EventRepeatsUntil')
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta metaTimeSpans ON (posts.ID = metaTimeSpans.post_id AND metaTimeSpans.meta_key = '_EventTimeRanges')
    WHERE posts.post_type = 'tribe_events'
    AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND meta.meta_value != 'once'
    AND '$queryDate 00:00:00' BETWEEN metaStartDate.meta_value AND metaRepeatsUntil.meta_value
 ";

// Execute the query using wpdb and fetch results as objects
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

if ($pageposts){
    global $post;
    foreach ($pageposts as $post){

        // Here's the loop magic
        setup_postdata($post);

        // Now you are free to use any common loop functions, such as
        // the_ID();
        // the_permalink();
        // the_title();
        // and all others.
        ?>

        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <h2>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </h2>
            <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <!-- by <?php the_author() ?> --></small>
            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
            </div>
            <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>  
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}else {
    // No results found
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe I need to reword my question, but there's a WP_Query object already in existence that I just want to add to without altering the template files (i.e. foreach'ing through the new results).  Any way to do that?

Comment: @tubaguy50035 well then please post your code, I'll see if it's possible to fit the solution into it.

Answer (score 0):

@turboguy50035 you can use the built in query mechanisms for the Tribe Events Calendar plugin to hook into the 'pre_get_posts' query filter. Although in my opinion the best option is just get the PRO plugin which adds recurrence into the query already.

Comment: Agreed and I wish I had that option.  It looks like I can override the one theme file that is giving me grief, so I'll move forward with that.

Comment: Based on your comment on another answer in this thread and your original question I'm still certain if you are looking to modify the query then hook into the pre_get_posts filter that the core Tribe plugin uses to modify your query results.